# how to change the loop to become a map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I haven't found a way to change for into a `map`, so my plan won't use for but want to use maps in each function of this function

```
variantDefault = (colorId, sizeId) => {
  let selected = [];
  let i = 0;
  if (this.props.index === 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.props.values.length; i++) {
      if (this.props.values[i].id === colorId) {
        selected = this.props.values[i];
      }
    }
  }
  if (this.props.index === 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < this.props.values.length; i++) {
      if (this.props.values[i].id === sizeId) {
        selected = this.props.values[i];
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(selected);
  return selected;
};
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to use `Array.map`? Please explain your question more. Also add all relevant code.

Comment: please add `this`, what you get and what does not work.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You might not even need `map`. Something like `find` or `filter` might work. Please post the expected behavior instead of attempted solution

Comment: If this is supposed to be trying to use `Array#map` then it's incorrect, since the method is not at all designed to do this. If this is about [the `Map` data structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) then I'm not sure how it relates to the question.

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` is for array A[n] and return an array A'  with the same length (n). I think what you need here is  `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: @TamDc or probably `.filter`

Comment: @VLAZ you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this way

```
variantDefault = (colorId, sizeId) => {
let selected = [];
if (this.props.index === 0) {
   this.props.values.map((data) => {
    if(data.id === colorId){
    selected.push(data)
    }
  })
}
if (this.props.index === 1) {
this.props.values.map((data) => {
  if (data.id === sizeId) {
    selected.push(data)
  }
})
}
console.log(selected);
return selected;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and return the found item.

```
variantDefault = (colorId, sizeId) => this.props.values.find(
    ({ id }) => id === [colorId, sizeId][this.props.index]
) || [];
```

Comment: The question is really unclear. I would have gone with `.find`, too but it breaks the current behaviour where it returns the *last* item that matches because it continually overwrites `selected` with each match found.

Comment: i know, but if the given code works, then i assume a unique result.

Comment: @NinaScholz The code in the question will return the last element found whereas yours will return the first. (It's possible that op wanted to return the first or `push` and return all of them)

Comment: ok, some more part of the exegesis: *variantDefault* is singular. as long as op does not state what op wants or feed the question with some data, any answer is guessing.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `Array.prototype.filter` seems more fitting.

```js
variantDefault = (colorId, sizeId) => {
  if (this.props.index.isBetween(0, arguments.length, 1)) return [];
  var compareTo = arguments[this.props.index];
  return this.props.values.filter(item => item.id === compareTo);
};
```

If you only want to return the last element found (which is what you are doing in your example) then add an `Array.prototype.pop` call to the filtered array.

You can add the `isBetween` function by doing:

```js
if (typeof Number.prototype.isBetween !== "function") {
  Number.prototype.isBetween = function(start, end, inclusive) {
    if (typeof start !== "number" || isNaN(start)) throw Error("Start is not a number");
    if (typeof end !== "number" || isNaN(end)) throw Error("End is not a number");
    return inclusive ? start <= this && this <= end : start < this && this < end;
  };
}
```